# How can I compare a expiracion date to be more than NOW() in a MSQL query? I'm trying to validate an expiration date, with a MYSQL query

Tags: mysql, validation

This is my code that should work but... it doesnt:

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE token = 'token#' AND expiration_date >= now();
```

the wierd thing is.. when i do "<=" it bring me dates greater than the actual time.
Maybe is something with the now() configuration time or something.

Comment: If it's a date, then you should use [CURDATE()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_curdate)

Comment: Try doing: `SELECT NOW()` and see if that matches what time it is for your timezone. You might have your timezone set wrong.

Comment: This is the format on my field "'2015-11-18 01:49:26'" is not just the date, i checked the timezone, with the SELECT NOW() and its fine

Answer (score 0):

Comparing the expiration date with  now() would only work that way if the data type of expiration_date is datetime else just use

`SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE token =
'token#' AND expiration_date >= CURTIME();`

if you are comparing with TIME.

or
`SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE token =
'token#' AND expiration_date >= CURDATE();`

if you are comparing with the DATE.

I think it's just best to set expiration_date as datetime and then compare with now()

Comment: Thank you very much for answering, i saw my problem, my field it was indeed datetime but i was setting the expiration_date wrong, i have a method that adds 1 hour to the creation time and it sets the expiration_date, but i dont know why its adding it but it comes from :2015-11-18 13:59:54,  to :2015-11-18 03:00:19, so when i do a ">= NOW()" at   2015-11-18 14:00:54 it came out false

Comment: My task now, will see how can i properly add 1 hour to my creation_time and set the expiration_date rigth.
I was doing
$expirationtime = date("Y-m-d h:i:s", strtotime("+ 1 hour"));